# ...(,) и не знаю, когда вернусь

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

1. Я поехал на дачонку(,) и не знаю, когда таки вернусь.

Comment: Всё-таки простое. По смыслу связаны глаголы, одна мысль, фраза... Можно сделать ССП, но тогда пауза и типа присоединение.

Comment: Эх, принимаете всё подряд, и верное и неверное.

Comment: А откуда в слове "датчонка" взялась буква "т"?

Comment: По-случайному, сэр. А сколько вам годиков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Я поехал на дачОнку, и не знаю, когда таки вернУсь.***

Это предложение можно считать ***ССП*** (запятая ставится) по следующим **показателям**: разный вид предложений (двусоставное и односоставное определенно-личное), разное время, наличие собственных распространителей.

Также по интонации здесь делается **два ударения** и, соответственно, произношение с паузой.

Comment: Но есть же общее подлежащие – *я*!

Comment: Во втором предложении нет грамматического подлежащего "я".  Просто по семантике мыслится общий субъект действия, Попробуем составить  предложение с такой основой:  Я поехал и не знаю.  Можно ли считать такие сказуемые однородными, что за действие они обозначают? В действительности в заданном предложении два сообщения и два разных вида предложений по грамматике.

Comment: На два однородных сказуемых тоже ставятся два ударения.

Comment: Сказал Олид  –  и замолчал. Что же он скажет дальше?

Comment: Не, ну вы утверждаете, что два ударения — два простых предложения, а это не так.

Comment: Да, можно: *Я поехал и не знаю, когда вернусь.* Всё чётко!

Comment: Здесь одна мысль, а вы на две разбиваете. Зачем? Вторая мысль пришла чуть позже? Возможно. Но это никак не основной вариант, это маловероятный вариант.